# filtering most recent of duplicate firebase documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m working with an angular 6 application that uses a firebase database. I’m wondering how to filter a list of documents for unique records according to a specific field and only the most recent ones.

For example, I have a collection of invitations that look like this:

```
{
    name: ‘Joe Shmoe’,
    email: ‘jshmoe@gmail.com'
    InvitedOn: ‘Sat Nov 3 2018 12:00PM’
}
```

Each person can be invited multiple times, so the collection may contain several invitations for Joe Schmoe, but they will all have different dates/times for the InvitedOn property.

What I’d like to do is:

- Group the documents by email.
- For each group, sort by date invited.
- Remove duplicate invites by taking the most recent one.

I’m not familiar enough with firebase to know how to do this. I’m working in angular 6 like I said, so I would very much appreciate if someone could explain how to do this in typescript/javascript, or direct me to a good site that explains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prevent duplicates by testing (querying) the database for its existence. If it already exists, update what's already there vs writing a whole new record.

Firestore offers better compound query functionality than Firebase Realtime Database. Unless you have a reason not to, use Firestore.

Reading and Deleting (removing) are distinct from one another. Just because you read the most recent record does not mean that record is deleted from the database, you would have to delete it also (if that's what you want to do).

So, the answer is to switch over to Firestore, don't record duplicate data, and lastly, store your timestamps as `Date.now()` timestamps so you're working with simple number comparisons to search by.

Comment: Thanks both. I took your advice and overwrote the invite in the database instead of keeping multiple copies.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to show a list of email addresses with the latest date they were invited on. If that's what you need, I'd recommend modeling precisely that in your database. Assuming Cloud Firestore, it'd look something like:

```
emails_with_invites (collection)
  jshmoe@gmail.com (document id)
    lastInvitedOn: ‘Sat Nov 3 2018 12:00PM’
```

With a collection like this the email address is automatically unique (your "group by" requirement) and you automatically have the last invite date. The price for this, is that you'll have to update this additional collection whenever you write an invite. You can either do this in the app code itself, or using Cloud Functions.